# Copy files to new directory and change filename - but leave old file in old directory

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get image files from one directory and copy it to a new directory with a new filename.
The code I am using - cobbled together from several forums - works, sort of, but deletes the file from the original directory.  How do I leave the original intact?

Please help

```
Sub MoveFiles()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim numRows As Long
   Dim oldFileName As String
   Dim newFileName As String

   With Sheets("Sheet1")
      'get number of rows to loop through
      numRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      For i = 2 To numRows
         '====================
         'old file
         '====================
         'build the path, test for end backslash in path for OLD filename
         oldFileName = .Range("A" & i).Value
         'If Right(oldFileName, 1) <> "\" Then oldFileName = oldFileName & "\"

         'add the file name
         oldFileName = oldFileName & .Range("B" & i).Value

         'does the file exist?
         If Not FileFolderExists(oldFileName) Then
            'highlight cell when OLD file doesn't exist, and skip to next row
            .Range("A" & i).Font.Color = vbBlue
          GoTo NextLoopIndex
         End If


         '==============
         'new file
         '============
         'test for end backslash in path for NEW filename
         newFileName = .Range("C" & i).Value
         If Right(newFileName, 1) <> "\" Then newFileName = oldFileName & "\"
         CreateFullPath newFileName
         'add on the filename
         newFileName = newFileName & .Range("F" & i).Value

         '==================
         'move file
         '===============
         Name oldFileName As newFileName

NextLoopIndex:
        oldFileName = ""
       newFileName = ""

      Next i
   End With
End Sub




Private Sub CreateFullPath(ByVal FilePath As String)
   Dim Folders  As Variant
   Dim tmp As String
   Dim i As Long

   'does the folder exist?
   If Not FileFolderExists(FilePath) Then
      If MsgBox("File path does not exist. Do you want to create it?", _
                Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then


         'build the folders
         Folders = Split(FilePath, "\")
         For i = LBound(Folders) To UBound(Folders) - 1
            tmp = tmp & Folders(i) & "\"
            If Not FileFolderExists(tmp) Then MkDir tmp
         Next i
      Else
         Exit Sub
      End If
   End If
End Sub




Private Function FileFolderExists(ByVal FilePath As String) As Boolean
   If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Name oldFileName As newFileName`, the [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement), as per the documentation,

> renames a file and moves it to a different directory or folder, if necessary.

Use [`FileCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filecopy-statement) to copy:

```
FileCopy oldFileName, newFileName
```

Comment: BigBen - brilliant - really appreciated